# orderBy is not updating when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hope somebody can help me with my problem. 
I am trying to order my list on specific data and this works fine when I say upfront on what it needs to be sorted. 
But when I do this when I click on a button it doesn't order my list in anyway.

Hope somebody can help me with this problem.

this is my app.js code:

```
app.controller("ListController", function ($scope, $interval, $http, myService, OpenDataService) {
    myService.async().then(function (d) {

        OpenDataService.opendata = d;

        $scope.openData = OpenDataService.opendata;
        $scope.order = "";



    });

    $scope.orderOptions = ["gemeente", "locatie"];


    $scope.change = function (value) {
        console.log("change");

        $scope.order = value;
        console.log(value);
    }
    $scope.test = OpenWifiData;


});
```

And here is the html code I use:

```
<li ng-click="change('gemeente')"><a>locatie</a></li>
<div id="WifiSpots" ng-controller="ListController" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <div  ng-repeat="item in openData | filter:searchText | orderBy: order">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row wifiSpots" >
                                <div class="col-md-2">{{item.locatie}}</div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">{{item.gemeente}}</div>
                                <div clas="col-md-1">{{item.distance}}</div>
                                <div clas="col-md-1">{{item.duration}}</div>
                                <button ng-controller="MapController" ng-click="calculateAndDisplayRoute(item.objectid)" class="btn ">Selecteer</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try to pu your ng-click on the a tag

Comment: The ng-click is working correctly and is also changing the value. The only problem that the changed value doesn't get picked up by my orderBy:

Answer (score 0):

The 'order' in the ng-repeat directive is in a different scope than the one in your controller. Add a wrapper class like so:

```
$scope.opts = {order: ""};
```

Then in your change function update that instead:

```
$scope.opts.order = value;
```

In the html:

```
orderBy:opts.order
```

Comment: Do you maybe a plunker for me ? I am trying your solution and I edited the first part in my Listcontroller. The second one in my change method. The third on in my orderBy: but for some reason it still doesn't order it :(

Comment: So strange I used your code in mine the same way you did. But it stil doesn't update :( It changes the variable correct in the change method but the orderBy doesn't do anything.

Comment: Maybe a little more information would help. Is the ng-click outside of your ListController on the actual site?

Comment: My ng-click is inside the ListController and I can also call the $scope.change method from that ng-click. When I click on it it also changes the variable accordingly. The only thing is that it looks like it doesn't orderBy with the new variable